# Can a fork child determine whether it is a fork or a vfork?

Tags: c, linux, fork, vfork

Within the child process, is there any way that it determine whether it was launched as a fork with overlay memory, or a vfork with shared memory?

Basically, our logging engine needs to be much more careful (and not log some classes of activity) in vfork. In fork it needs to cooperate with the parent process in ways that it doesn't in vfork. We know how to do those two things, but not how to decide.

I know I could probably intercept the fork/vfork/clone calls, and store the fork/vfork/mapping status as a flag, but it would make life somewhat simpler if there was an API call the child could make to determine its own state.

Extra marks: Ideally I also need to pick up any places in libraries that have done a fork or vfork and then called back into our code. And how that can happen? At least one of the libraries we have offers a popen-like API where a client call-back is called from the fork child before the exec. Clearly the utility of that call-back is significantly restricted in vfork.

Comment: Pass the child this info as parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the thought @EugeneSh. That's similar complexity to intercepting fork/vfork. It also means changing the "business logic" to support "diagnostics". Tough sell. Also won't pick up any places in libraries that have done a fork and then called back into our code.

Comment: BTW; you cannot intercept `vfork()` because the `vfork()` child must not ever return from the function that called it. Writing a libc wrapper `vfork() => clone()` proved intractable due to register pressure.

Comment: [Friends don't let friends call `vfork()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/vfork.html): "The use of `vfork()` for any purpose except as a prelude to an immediate call to a function from the `exec` family, or to `_exit()`, is not advised."  `vfork()` is also extremely nasty to multithreaded processes.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The world is changed and `vfork()` is making a comeback. `posix_spawn()` is implemented in terms of `vfork()` and nobody's reported multithreaded issues because they don't exist.

Comment: @Joshua *`posix_spawn()` is implemented in terms of `vfork()`*  So `vfork()` and then `exec()` per the POSIX warnings is a "comeback"?  Ooooh-kay.

Comment: As compared to "friends don't let friends call vfork" it sure is.

Comment: @Joshua Did you even bother to read the [semantics of `vfork()` from the Linux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html)? "the behavior is undefined if the process created by `vfork()` either modifies any data other than a variable of type `pid_t` used to store the return value from `vfork()`, or returns from the function in which `vfork()` was called, or calls any other function before successfully calling `_exit(2)` or one of the `exec(3)` family of functions"  How is something that's undefined behavior if it modifies any memory or calls any function making a comeback?

Comment: And how is "`vfork()` differs from `fork(2)` in that the calling thread is suspended until the child terminates" ***not*** "nasty to a multithreaded process"?  "All you other threads can run, but this one here is stuck until this child process terminates somehow..."

Comment: @Joshua Oh, almost forgot:  the ***reason*** `vfork()` had to make a "comeback" on Linux in the first place is because [glibc broke `fork()`](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19703).  There was [even an attempt to get POSIX to drop the requirement that `fork()` be async-signal-safe](https://www.opengroup.org/austin/docs/austin_446.txt), most likely from the glibc developers, I'd guess.  Since that was 12 years ago and POSIX still requires `fork()` to be async-signal-safe, the reply seems to have been, "Naaah, glibc, `fork()` isn't too hard for everyone else. Fix your library"

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Are you sure it isn't the 1+GB worth of pagefaults paid every time something like Qt calls `fork()`, because that's what it was for me.

Comment: @Joshua So how many page faults did the subsequent `exec*()` call cause?  Because you didn't do something like invoke undefined behavior by modifying memory or making function calls after `vfork()` in something as complex as a Qt application, did you?  I mean, that would be an extremely low standard to write code to, after all.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I tested for this. Every writable page in the parent process faults the next time it's written to even if the child has already called `exec()` and isn't sharing memory any more. These faults are handled in kernel, but you still have to transition to kernel to handle them. With KPTI, that's expensive.

Comment: Do you need a POSIX solution, or is a nonportable Linux-only solution okay?

Comment: When `fork()` is expensive or problematic (see any service daemon), you create a child process that does it for you *once* (as early as possible in the lifetime of said process), and transfer the information needed by subsequent child processes – even file descriptors – via a socket pair.  This is not difficult.  I find it telling that instead of solving the underlying problem (high cost of fork) via this method, "developers" are breaking things in an effort to lower the cost.  Sigh.

Comment: Having done it I can say that it /is/ possible to intercept vfork and provide the same guarantees to the parent process, but it involves backing up and restoring stack frames between the intercept and the real call - not pretty! The same for the equivalent clone. It is much easier to simply intercept vfork and implement it as fork!

Comment: @Glärbo, though, to be honest, that's not really fixing the high cost of fork(), just working around it. It does sound like a better workaround than a cross-your-fingers-and-hope-it-works sharing like vfork(), but a workaround it is. (Seriously, I wonder how that "[can't modify] any data other than a variable of type pid_t used to store the return value" even works without assumptions about what sort of the code the compiler creates. Unless the idea is that modifying that pid_t is ok since the parent will execute afterwards and overwrite it so everything should be just fine...)

Comment: @Joshua, do you happen have that test code somewhere? It would be interesting to see.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Oh, I fully agree; I probably should have written something like "avoiding the high cost of fork()".  The key thing is that when you have a large multithreaded process, forking (or cloning) will be expensive because a lot of details are involved; and all shortcuts like vfork() have always had their issues.  One can *avoid* those by having a minimal helper child process do it instead.  It is nothing new, a pattern used in Unix service daemons for decades now.  Apparently Unix is a swear word nowadays...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution could use [pthread_atfork()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_atfork). The callbacks registered with this service are triggered only upon `fork()`. So, the 3rd parameter of the function, which is called in the child process right after the fork, could update a global variable. The child can check the variable and if it is modified, then it has been forked:

```c
/*
  Simple program which demonstrates a solution to
  make the child process know if it has been forked or vforked
*/
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pid_t forked;

void child_hdl(void)
{
  forked = getpid();
}


int main(void)
{
pid_t pid;

  pthread_atfork(0, 0, child_hdl);

  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    if (forked != 0) {
      printf("1. It is a fork()\n");
    }
    exit(0);
  }

  // Father continues here
  wait(NULL);

  pid = vfork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    if (forked != 0) {
      printf("2. It is a fork()\n");
    }
    _exit(0);
  }

  // Father continues here
  wait(NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Build/execution:

```
$ gcc fork_or_vfork.c
$ ./a.out
1. It is a fork()
```

Comment: Improvement: stuff pid into the variable so you can detect vfork inside of fork. But now you have to initialize the variable with pid at startup somehow.

Comment: This is the least intrusive of the suggestions - so accepted!  I would suggest that the comparison is that `(getpid()==forked)` because you could vfork from within a fork. I still need to distinguish the vfork from the original parent - using a static constructor for it `pid_t forked = getpid();` is probably acceptable.

Comment: (and I should read other peoples comments)

Answer (score 6):

All code not specifically designed to work under `vfork()` doesn't work under `vfork()`.

Technically, you can check if you're in a `vfork()` child by calling `mmap()` and checking if the memory mapping was inherited by the parent process under `/proc`. Do not write this code. It's a really bad idea and nobody should be using it. Really, the best way to tell if you're in a `vfork()` child or not is to be passed that information. But here comes the punchline. What are you going to do with it?

The things you can't do as a `vfork()` child include calling `fprintf()`, `puts()`, `fopen()`, or any other standard I/O function, nor `malloc()` for that matter. Unless the code is very carefully designed, you're best off not calling into your logging framework at all, and if it is carefully designed you don't need to know. A better design would most likely be log your intent before calling `vfork()` in the first place.

You ask in comments about a library calling `fork()` and then back into your code. That's already kind of bad. But no library should ever *ever* call `vfork()` and back into your code without being explicitly documented as doing so. `vfork()` is a constrained environment and calling things not expected to be in that environment really should not happen.

Answer (score 0):

I came across `kcmp` today, which looks like it can answer the basic question - i.e. do two tids or pids share the same VM. If you know they represent forked parent/child pids, this can perhaps tell you if they are vfork()ed.

Of course if they are tids in the same process group then they will by definition share VM.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kcmp.2.html

```
int syscall(SYS_kcmp, pid_t pid1, pid_t pid2, int type,
               unsigned long idx1, unsigned long idx2);
```

KCMP_VM
Check whether the processes share the same address space.
The arguments idx1 and idx2 are ignored.  See the
discussion of the CLONE_VM flag in clone(2).

Comment: This may work on Linux, but be careful: POSIX says "the behavior is undefined if the process created by vfork() [...] calls any other function before successfully calling _exit() or one of the exec family of functions."

Comment: Thanks @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica There are lots of issues with doing anything in for or vfork, of course.

Answer (score -3):

If you were created by `vfork`, your parent will be waiting for you to terminate. Otherwise, it's still running. Here's some *very* ugly code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

void doCheck()
{
    char buf[512];
    sprintf(buf, "/proc/%d/wchan", (int) getppid());
    int j = open(buf, O_RDONLY);
    if (j < 0) printf("No open!\n");
    int k = read(j, buf, 500);
    if (k <= 0) printf("k=%d\n", k);
    close(j);
    buf[k] = 0;
    char *ptr = strstr(buf, "vfork");
    if (ptr != NULL)
       printf("I am the vfork child!\n");
    else
       printf("I am the fork child!\n");   
}

int main()
{
    if (fork() == 0)
    {
       doCheck();
       _exit(0);
    }
    sleep(1);
    if (vfork() == 0)
    {
        doCheck();
        _exit(0);
    }
    sleep(1);
}
```

This is not perfect, the parent might be waiting for a subsequent `vfork` call to complete.

Comment: Doesn't work. D could be the parent thread in a non-interruptible IO call. While they say NFS; these happen briefly even on local filesystems.

Comment: It's also unsafe - you can't call things like `*printf()` from within a `vfork()` child.  If one of those calls uses `malloc()`/`free()`, the parent process heap could be corrupted, or the `vfork()` child could deadlock. Of course, `vfork()` is already playing with fire, so...

Comment: The `printf` calls are just to demonstrate the technique which only requires `open`, `read`, and `close`.

Comment: Calling any one of `open()`, `read()`, or `close()` in a `vfork`ed child produces undefined behavior according to POSIX, too.  The options are few: store the return value of `vfork` in an object of type `pid_t`, call `_exit()` (but not `exit()`), or call one of the exec functions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: You can also call anything that's async-signal-safe and isn't multi-threaded (nothing in pthread.h). But anything you write to in the child becomes undefined in the parent. I use this for clearing signal handlers in the child and setting up which signals the child should ignore.